# Unity camera zoom for specific object (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, zooming

I would like to zoom forward and backward on specific elements only in 2D.

- I have an orthographic camera.
- I have a canvas containing UI elements that must not change size or
  position.
- I also have some elements in this canvas that must be zoomed in or
  out.

An image is worth 1000 words:  http://prntscr.com/ljjp8i

I want to zoom on the background (which is an image) and the cercles on it, but not on buttons/text arround the game view.

I already made some test with the following code:

```
   void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0) // back
        {
            Debug.Log("zoom out");
            cam.orthographicSize +=1;

        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0) // forward
        {
            Debug.Log("zoom in");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not do anything. Even though the DEbug.Log comes in, there is no change in the view.
Moreover, I have no idea how it would react on all the UI elements, how to exclude elements that must not be "zoomed".

Is someone able to point me out a good resource that explains how to achieve this, or to give me guidelines soe that I can explore on my own? (Or even give the solution if you are up to ^^)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the canvas is set to render in `Screen Space`.

You should consider creating a separate canvas for the objects that you want to scale. Set the render mode of that canvas to `World Space`, and it should be affected by the orthographic size of the camera.

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm for zooming in. I still have a problem with zooming out, it seems like the image is "doubling" when I zoom backward further than it was at the very first state. Here is a screen, any idea what's going on? http://prntscr.com/ljl684

Comment: Check your camera. Make sure that `Clear Flags` is set to `Solid Color` or `SkyBox`.